# Delaying Startup Services; Faster boot

Tags: boot, services

I really liked how Windows boot faster than Ubuntu. I think, Windows only ran the basic services needed to operate minimally. Then Start the services when it's booted. So it seems Windows is booting faster.

If that's what Windows does, Can I do the same with Ubuntu?
I tried  `systemd-analyze blame`. It shows-

> 4.214s plymouth-quit-wait.service
> 7.683s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> 6.163s snapd.service
> 5.592s networkd-dispatcher.service
> 4.734s dev-sda8.device
> 4.486s udisks2.service
> 3.630s accounts-daemon.service
> 3.601s apport-autoreport.service
> 2.885s NetworkManager.service
> 2.671s polkit.service
> 2.586s dev-loop8.device
> 2.546s dev-loop10.device
> 2.475s dev-loop9.device
> 2.452s dev-loop7.device
> 2.366s dev-loop1.device
> 2.232s dev-loop5.device
> 2.216s avahi-daemon.service
> 2.181s dev-loop0.device
> 2.144s dev-loop2.device
> 2.140s switcheroo-control.service
> 2.136s thermald.service
> 2.136s systemd-logind.service
> 2.134s wpa_supplicant.service

How can I delay the services a bit so that it boots faster & I'll be able to log in faster...
Most of the cases I open the Firefox(start browsing) right after Logging in & sometimes I open  Nautilus, but that's it. My guess is delaying some services won't cause any issues.

Please suggest me How can I do it...

I currently Have only these startup applications

[image: I currently Have only these startup applications]

Comment: You can stop some of those from even running with no ill effects for a regular desktop user. See [here](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2019/11/28/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-linux-if-it-boots-slowly/).

Comment: The page you linked, has steps to stop unwanted services. Is there a chance that those will affect my usage?

Comment: Nah, you'll be fine without them. You can (and should) look 'em up to see what they do. If you don't use snap apps then you can disable that one too. You should use the page as a guide but read about each service before you decide to disable 'em. Or you can just blindly copy and paste 'em and hope for the best! (Just pay attention to what you disable/remove and bookmark the page should you want to undo them.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll then Manually check my services & see how much time I can save. Thanks a lot bro.

I'm also thinking to use [E4rat](https://www.howtogeek.com/69753/how-to-cut-your-linux-pcs-boot-time-in-half-with-e4rat/)

Comment: The ones listed on the page can be disabled by the average desktop user with no ill effects. If you mask or disable any services not listed, keep track and you can enable them again if things go pear shaped. If you don't use, or intend to use, snap apps then you can completely remove the snapd application.